# Multi-digit recognition with Keras: How to Implement Independent Fully Connected Layers

Tags: keras

I'm trying to classify an image with multiple digits. Say an image with "123" to output "123". There are up to 5 digits.

I'm stuck after I built the convolution layers. How do we output 5 digits each with 10 classes? Some suggested 5 independent fully connected layers after the final convolution layer. But how do we code this in Keras for the 5 independent FCs?

Answer (score 0):

divide image to one image 
make classifier for 1 digit 
use for each part of image

if you cant divide, try sliding -window